# How to deploy, start, stop an OSGI bundle programmatically using java and a remote karaf container?

Tags: osgi, apache-karaf

I'm completely new to OSGI , and I have developed a compiler which converts a DSL to an OSGI bundle, and now I would like to manage these bundles programmatically (start, stop, deploy) using java and a remote Karaf container, and I'm wondering if it is possible , if so how can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most karaf native way to do this is to also create a feature per DSL bundle. This way you can install the feature repo and feature which also installs the bundle. This approach also allows to deploy/undeploy dependencies the bundle might have. To use this you deploy the bundle and feature to a maven repo and install using this repo url. You can use the [jmx beans](https://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest/#_jmx_featurembean) to trigger the feature installation.

Another possible way is to install the bundle directly via jmx. I do not have the actual doc reference for it but you can simply check the beans via jconsole.